# delete more than one row at a time numpy array python

Tags: numpy, row

I want to delete all row after the second row, however, when I try to apply the following code, the function delete only the third and the 5th rows and keep the forth any idea on how to improve this without doing a loop

```
arr1 = array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
arr2 = array([[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]])
arr1 = concatenate((arr1, arr2), axis=0)
print(arr1)
print(delete(arr1, (2, 4), axis=0))
```

Comment: `arr1[:2]` should return the first 2 rows.

Comment: With `delete` you have to list all rows that you want to delete, not just the end points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data you want to delete is contiguous (like in your example), using numpy's array indexing is arguably the easiest way to achieve what you want.

```
import numpy as np 

arr1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
arr2 = np.array([[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]])
arr3 = np.r_[arr1, arr2]

# First dimension corresponds to rows, second dimension corresponds to columns. 
print(arr3[:2, :])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass a tuple as the second argument.

```py
>>> Arr = array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
>>> delete(Arr, (0, 2), axis=0)
array([[4, 5, 6]])
```

Btw, `delete(Arr, (3), axis=0)` does not work in your example, since the maximum index for this array is 2.

Concerning your edit, the error is the same as above: you are using an index (3 or 5) which does not correspond to an actual index of the array. `Arr[3]` or `Arr[5]` does not make any sense for an array of shape `(3,3)`.

Comment: thank you for your reply I adjust the post and explain the problem in more details can you please look at it again

Comment: Done. Btw, this is not an error but a Warning. The difference is that the Warning won't stop the execution of your code. However, it is important that you understand why you get this warning if you want to understand what the function `delete` actually does.

Comment: thanks that was my mistake the maximum index is 4 not 5, but still that not what I want, I want to delete all rows after the second row however, the function only delete the 3th and the 5th row and keeps the 4th row

Comment: Do you remember that in Python, arrays are indexed starting from 0? The 4th column has index `3`, the first one `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it works well

```
arr1 = array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
arr2 = array([[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]])
arr1 = concatenate((arr1, arr2), axis=0)
print(arr1)
print(delete(arr1, (range(2, 5)), axis=0))
```